# How to assign a group to previous n rows in r

Tags: r

In the data frame below, I'd like to create a new column ("grp") that assigns the row with an assigned "R" and the previous 2 a value of "yes". I am unsure how to call the 2 preceding rows from when `R != NA`.

```
structure(list(ID = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), RunTime = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3), 
Rad = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200), R = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.9, NA, NA, NA, 0.8)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

The resultant data frame should look like this.

```
ID  RunTime  Rad  R    grp
11  0        100  NA   NA
11  1        100  NA   yes
11  2        100  NA   yes
11  3        100  0.9  yes
11  0        200  NA   NA
11  1        200  NA   yes
11  2        200  NA   yes
11  3        200  0.8  yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming only a single non-NA per each group, we create the index based on the `is.na` with `which`  add a sequence of values, and `replace` with "yes"

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 2
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID, Rad) %>% 
   mutate(grp = replace(rep(NA_character_, n()), which(!is.na(R)) + -n:0, "yes"))
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   ID, Rad [2]
#     ID RunTime   Rad     R grp  
#  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#1    11       0   100  NA   <NA> 
#2    11       1   100  NA   yes  
#3    11       2   100  NA   yes  
#4    11       3   100   0.9 yes  
#5    11       0   200  NA   <NA> 
#6    11       1   200  NA   yes  
#7    11       2   200  NA   yes  
#8    11       3   200   0.8 yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this in base R :

```
#Get position of non-NA value in R
inds <- which(!is.na(df$R))
#Create index to replace
new_inds <- c(inds - 1, inds - 2, inds)
#Keep only positive value and the unique ones
new_inds <- unique(new_inds[new_inds > 0])
#Initialise grp with NA
df$grp <- NA
#Replace `new_inds` with 'yes'
df$grp[new_inds] <- 'yes'
df

#  ID RunTime Rad   R  grp
#1 11       0 100  NA <NA>
#2 11       1 100  NA  yes
#3 11       2 100  NA  yes
#4 11       3 100 0.9  yes
#5 11       0 200  NA <NA>
#6 11       1 200  NA  yes
#7 11       2 200  NA  yes
#8 11       3 200 0.8  yes
```